# How to run Oracle 's sql developer sdcli command line tool on Linux headless?

Tags: oracle, cron, oracle-sqldeveloper, headless

I had our sysadmins install Oracle SQL Developer and JDK 8 on a linux box so that I can run some reports from cron.  However, I can't seem to get SQL Developer's sdcli command to run without an X Display.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I'm ssh'ing into the box from a Windows machine (running Cygwin).  I do not want to run X since my goal

The output I see is:

```
$ sdcli reports help

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

$ echo $?
0
```

If I run it as "bash -x sdcli reports help", I get a lot more output, but nothing is helping me:

```
++ /opt/jdk8/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/jdk8/lib/tools.jar:/opt/jdk8/lib/dt.jar -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dnetbeans.home=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/ -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -Dexcluded.modules=org.eclipse.osgi -Dide.cluster.dirs=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/fcpbridge/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/ide/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/../ -Xverify:none -Doracle.ide.extension.HooksProcessingMode=LAZY -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:bundles.info -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=1 -Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=false -Dosgi.noShutdown=true '-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*' -Dosgi.parentClassloader=app -Dosgi.locking=none -Dosgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app -Xbootclasspath/p:../../ide/bin/../../rdbms/jlib/ojdi.jar -Dosgi.classloader.type=parallel -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dide.feedback-server=ide.us.oracle.com -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.ide.xml.switchable.SwitchableTransformerFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.util.XMLEventAllocator=oracle.ideimpl.xml.stream.XMLEventAllocatorImpl -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations=bug -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations.exceptionsfile=../../ide/bin/../../ide/bin/swing-thread-violations.conf -Xms128M -Xmx800M -Doracle.ide.IdeFrameworkCommandLineOptions=-clean,-console,-debugmode,-migrate,-migrate:,-nomigrate,-nonag,-nondebugmode,-noreopen,-nosplash,-role:,-su -Dide.update.usage.servers=http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dwindows.shell.font.languages= -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.conf -Dsqldev.debug=false -Dsqldev.onsd=true -Dapplication.handle.help=true -Dno.shell.integration=true -Dnetbeans.security.nocheck=true -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true '-Dide.conf="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sdcli.conf"' '-Duser.conf="/home/dsm26/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/product.conf"' '-Dtool.user.conf="/home/dsm26/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/sdcli.conf"' '-Dide.startingcwd="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin"' -classpath ../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/ide-boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/fcpboot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/xml-factory.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar:../lib/oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher reports help
++ exitCode=2
++ ProductCanRestart
++ '[' X = X ']'
++ return 1
++ CanRestart=1
++ '[' 1 = 0 ']'
++ '[' 2 = 245 ']'
++ '[' 2 -gt 0 ']'
+++ /opt/jdk8/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/jdk8/lib/tools.jar:/opt/jdk8/lib/dt.jar -version
++ s='java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)'
+++ expr 'java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)' : 'java version \"1\.[0-3]'
++ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+++ expr 'java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)' : 'java version \"1\.[0-9].*\"'
++ '[' 23 -le 0 ']'
++ return 2
```

Thanks for your help.  Fyi...I had to chmod 755 both sqldeveloper.sh and ide/bin/launcher.sh after my sysadmin did the install.

I'm on Centos 6.7 (Final)

Thank you,
Don

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer for your question but I wanted to point out that for exactly that purpose Oracle have introduced a new SQL command line called [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html). It essentially is the SQL Developer SQL execution engine packaged as a standalone Java command line utility. Perhaps worth a try.

Comment: what linux? On Oracle Linux, ./sdcli reports runs the program and gives me the usage info for running a report.

Comment: I'm on CentOS release 6.7 (Final).  The uname -a output is:  2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 13 22:55:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: We confirmed that on Oracle Linux our installation worked.  So it looks like an issue on CentOS.  I'm not 100% positive we have a good install on CentOS, but we will probably go with an Oracle Linux box.